# Split multi-selection answer to different columns in Excel or Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a column from the answer to the multiselection multiple choice question. Like this:

| Answer |
| --- |
| Dog, Cat, Bird |
| Dog, Bird |
| Dog, Fish |
| Cat |

I would like to split them into different columns for visualization:

| Dog | Cat | Bird | Fish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

How I can do that in Excel or Python? Thank you!

Comment: It is a good thing you included examples out expected output, but we need to see what you tried. Show us your code so we can suggest improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using pandas and string answers:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lst = ['Dog, Cat, Bird', 'Dog, Bird', 'Dog, Fish', 'Cat']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'answer':lst})
>>> df
           answer
0  Dog, Cat, Bird
1       Dog, Bird
2       Dog, Fish
3             Cat
```

You can now split each string into a list of strings, and check if each answer is in that list:

```
>>> df.answer = df.answer.str.split(', ')  # split strings to list 
>>> for word in  ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Fish']:
...     df[word] = df.answer.apply(lambda x : 1 if word in x else 0)
>>> df
             answer  Dog  Cat  Bird  Fish
0  [Dog, Cat, Bird]    1    1     1     0
1       [Dog, Bird]    1    0     1     0
2       [Dog, Fish]    1    0     0     1
3             [Cat]    0    1     0     0
```

Use sets if you're having trouble creating a unique list of all answers (e.g. too many different answers):

```
>>> answer_set = set()
>>> for i in df.answer:
...     answer_set.update(set(i))
>>> answer_list = list(answer_set)
>>> answer_list
['Fish', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your column is a *list* of *lists*, like so `[['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'], ['Dog', 'Bird'], ['Dog', 'Fish'], ['Cat']]`.
2. You have a predefined amount of choices, which is also a *list*. Let's say `['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Fish']`.
3. Each column of your final visualization is also a *list* but with a single *key* (animal) related to it, which can be expressed as a *dict*. For instance, first column is `visu['Dog'] = [1, 1, 1, 0]`, and so on.
4. So, you can loop over your **choices** *list* and check if each animal is present in each *list* of your **answer** *list*. You can visualize that is necessary 2 loops. The lines below will give you a big clue, but not the final answer. It uses a *for* loop and the builtin *map* function, which has an implicit loop.

```
answer = [['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird'], ['Dog', 'Bird'], ['Dog', 'Fish'], ['Cat']]
choices = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Fish']

visu = {}
for animal in choices:
    visu[animal] = list(map(lambda x: animal in x, answer))

print(visu)
```

5. I recommend you to check some python tutorials and definition, mainly for the terms I formatted in italic.